# Jdbc connection class method setAutoCommit() behaviour

Tags: java, jdbc

What will happen if we use `setAutoCommit(true)` twice in Java class with oracle DB.

```
try{
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
}catch (exception ex){
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference. A second `connection.setAutoCommit(true)` call is simply not going to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

From Javadoc

> If setAutoCommit is called and the auto-commit mode is not changed, the call is a no-op.

So if you call `setAutoCommit()` with the same argument several times only first call will be executed. All subsequent calls with the same argument will be ignored.